# forward fill nulls with latest non null value over each column except first two

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that after my pivot it created rows with null values . I need to replace the null values with the latest non null value. And I need to do this over each column in the df except the first two

**Sample:**

```
columns = ['date', 'group', 'value', 'value2']
data = [\
        ('2020-1-1','b', 5, 20),\
        ('2020-2-1','a', None, 15),\
        ('2020-3-1','a', 20, None),\
        ('2020-3-1','b', 10, None),\
        ('2020-2-1','b', None, None),\
        ('2020-1-1','a', None, None),\
        ('2020-4-1','b', None, 100)]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

**Window function for ffill logic**

```
# fill nulls with previous non null value
plist = ['group']
ffill = Window.partitionBy(*plist).orderBy('date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
```

**Goal: I basically want to overwrite the value and value2 columns by replacing the nulls. THis is a sample but my actual df has over 30 columns. How can i loop through all of them , again, except col 1 & 2.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `last` function with *ignorenulls* set to `True` to get the last non-null value within a window (if all null then return null). For looping through all columns except the first two, you can use list comprehension.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, last

# all colums except the first two
cols = sdf.columns[2:]

sdf = sdf.select('date', 'group', 
                 *[last(col(c), ignorenulls=True).over(ffill).alias(c) for c in cols])
sdf.show()

# +--------+-----+-----+------+
# |    date|group|value|value2|
# +--------+-----+-----+------+
# |2020-1-1|    b|    5|    20|
# |2020-2-1|    b|    5|    20|
# |2020-3-1|    b|   10|    20|
# |2020-4-1|    b|   10|   100|
# |2020-1-1|    a| null|  null|
# |2020-2-1|    a| null|    15|
# |2020-3-1|    a|   20|    15|
# +--------+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: does it automatically fill ordered by the date column too ?

Comment: the code above uses `ffill` window that you've defined in your question, so yes